# Why my Storyboard can't initiate on simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, storyboard

I built a storyboard like this:

[image]

I didn't write a single line of code, and my settings seem to be correct.

[image]

So why do I always get a blank screen on simulator?

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: You need to specify storybord file name in info.plist file....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your app delegate explicitly creating `*window`? If so, delete that line of code.

```
// self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

But keep the property definition:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window; // keep this
```

Comment: thx,but didn't work, throw exception: reason: '-[TabTableAppDelegate setWindow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a179e0'

Comment: You're welcome. And don't worry - you're in good company. The Apple docs gloss this over because up to 5.x the window was in the main Nib and not explicitly created in code. But with XCode 4.whatever the project template for non-storyboard projects create the window object explicitly in code, which overrides the storyboard (or perhaps sits in front of it?) at run time. Anyway, may you reap the benefit of the hour it took me to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

@oratis have you checked in AppDelegate  @synthesize window = _window; it might be the reason for unrecognized selector